# angular2 with node routes issue

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I am currently working with angular2 and for deployment purpose I have to use node as my server .I am stuck in the routes

Success Scenario :

if I navigate to pages using **routerLink** it works fine node serve them well

route is: http://localhost:8080/sign-in --- works fine

Failure Scenario :
If I  enter address same as above manually in the address bar it couldn't load the page

i.e it stuck saying app-loading that is the index.html and other routes not working

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var path = require("path");



app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));


app.get('/[^\.]+$', function(req, res) {
  console.log(__dirname+'/src/index.html')
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/src/index.html'))
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

The issue is with node server that couldn't serve up the pages,but I want routes to work even from the address bar  any help will be highly appreciated
The app is for **production mode** with **angular 4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your angular project:**

Don't forger to build your project with **ng build**. After that, you will see a new directory: **dist**
This directory contains your angular project.

**In your node project:**

You have to send all the routes in your angular project with that:

```
// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'yourprojectangular/dist/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using HashLocationStrategy as LocationStrategy:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Try to change '/[^\.]+$' into '/*'

Comment: its working but url is now with a hashbang
i.e localhost:8080/#!/signin

Comment: it seems to be invisible for the user

Comment: What makes it working? the HashLocationStrategy  or changing  '/[^\.]+$' into '/*' ?

Comment: without using both of them i can now hit by adding hashbang